# The term "well enough"

Tags: meaning-in-context

[image: Can you read well enough to complete this survey?]

If I agree, am I agreeing that I can barely read it or that I can read it? In other words, may "well enough" be replaced with "just well enough"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Well enough* excludes *not well enough*, so it implies that you read **at least** well enough to read the story.

But it does not exclude your reading a little or even much better.

Answer (score 3):

A visual aide (supplement to StoneyB's excellent answer) to help further illuminate the matter for those of us who are more visually oriented.

(Please to do not give any votes for this answer that take votes away from Stoney's. His is the correct answer, and was first; mine is merely a supplement. I'd have edited the image into his answer but I didn't want to subject him to my terrible Paint skills!)

**Reading Level**

[image]

Note that the "Agree" line is *inclusive of* "Well Enough" while the "Disagree" line is not.